# Why is the Shift key suddenly stealing focus?

Tags: keyboard, 12.04

So, I'm using Precise Beta, and something strange is happening.  I understand the ALT key behaviour, that's okay, but it seems that the SHIFT key is doing something similar - that is, it doesn't do anything useful, afaics, but it causes the focus to be taken away from the current element while it's down.  Mostly this isn't a problem, but in certain cases where focus change triggers an event, it's a pain.

An example problem is in Firefox's Firebug, when entering values like `90%` for a css value; I'm unable to enter the `%` symbol, because once shift is down, it loses focus and the `90` disappears.

Any idea what's happening?

Comment: Interesting. I thought I was imagining that. It seems to sometimes launch HUD. I'm not able to reproduce it at will, though. In any case, it's a bug.

Comment: I'm still not convinced... it seems like there is some intention behind it as-of-yet-unrealized.  I just noticed that the ALT key behaviour gets in the way as well, in certain cases where ALT is used in a focused element, e.g. the Firefox address bar.  I guess overall it is buggy behaviour...

Comment: no time just now, but you're on to sth here! I was going to try to learn how to file a bug properly, but won't have time till next week. Shift + .. has some WEIRD behaviour going on in Precise (don't know about Oneiric, but was FINE in Natty); restart helps for a while, but it's kind of ridiculous ./

Comment: for instance, I can't (since precise) enter "(" or "&" (SHIFT 6 and SHIFT 8, resp., on my keyboard) in, for instance, naming a folder in nautilus, or even / also naming a group in Firefox's Panorama! What the? What it does: it either quits the creation & naming of a folder (in nautilus), or, as in naming a FF Panorama group, would just get rid of all I typed so far and start anew with the cursor at the (blank) beginning... Is [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compizconfig-settings-manager/+bug/933956) the most relevant one?

Comment: yet another example: can't even type a capital "S" (SHIFT s) in a field in Zotero (in Firefox). Gee...

Comment: another observation: **GEDIT** seems to be the _**only**_ application where the keyboard _reliably_ functions as it should !!!

Comment: add capital "T" to the list (as _not_ being typeable in a Zotero field in FF)...

Comment: This bug affects me too

Comment: Disabling `unity` in `ccsm` fixes this!

Comment: @Yuttadhammo I opened a new question http://askubuntu.com/questions/427463/

Comment: I'm also having this problem, what is too localized?